# What number completes this sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

What number completes this sequence please?

> 1, 2, 68, 14, 21, 89, 49, 56, 37, 95

Comment: Does the fact that 89 is 68 turned upside-down have anything to do with it?

Comment: @ZaniXu Well spotted, but no.

Comment: does the order of the numbers in the sequence you wrote matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **5**

because

> it almost creates a pattern when we take the amount of the numbers
>  (ex: 1 used 3 times, 2 used 2 times etc.)
>  1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9 (numbers)
>  3-2-1-2-2-2-1-2-3 (amount of numbers in the sequence)

so

> if we add 5 to the sequence the *amount of numbers from 1 to 9* is going to be a pattern itself like
> 3-2-1-2-3-2-1-2-3

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Isn't there a lot of possibilities then? Maybe I didn't understand, what allows us to choose one among the others?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Can you explain your question more?

Comment: What if I use 73 or 233456778? It would also make a pattern.

Comment: using 73 would make it 3-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-3, using the other one would make it 3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3. why would you want to go against the pattern that the question already gives?

Comment: If this is the right answer, then I would not consider the numbers in the question to be a sequence. Their order does not matter. The way the digits are composed into larger numbers does not matter. Those are essentially random aspects added to a collection of digits to make it look like a sequence even though it really isn't one. If the question had presented a (multi)set of digits and asked which one was missing, it would be more logical, but presenting it as a sequence is misleading and in my opinion then makes the answer rather unsatisfying.

Answer (score -3):

Does the fact that

> 14, 21, 49, 56, and 95 are all multiples of 7

have to do with it? My guess would be

> 102

Comment: I don't think 95 is a multiple of 7.

Comment: 102 isn't a multiple of 7 either... could you explain your reasoning a bit further, please?

Comment: Also, answers need to be hidden in spoiler tags. In the unlikely event that this *is* the correct answer, you're currently spoiling it for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves.

Comment: It has nothing to do with multiples.